# How to load a txt file into an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I coded a method to load a txt file into an array. However, I'm not really happy with it as it looks terribly cumbersome to my beginner's eyes (I'm sure I don't need 50% of my code) and I am somehow wondering how I can specify the exact format of my txt file, e.g. NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Here is my code:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.txt"]; 

if (filePath) { // check if file exists - if so load it:
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (myText) {textView.text=myText;}
}
```

For any suggestions of how to polish this up and specify the right format, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Into an array? You mean into a string, since is exactly what you're doing...

However, your code looks not bad, and most of it is just to grab the documents directory path, and that's not your fault, since it's exactly done this way, according to many knowledge bases.

As of the encoding, stringWithContentsOfFile is deprecated, please use stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error: (see the docs)
and you will be able to specify the correct encoding and get accurate error descriptions.

Comment: @Nick Weaver: afaik, documents directory != resources directory

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, assuming your file is in your bundle:

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"txt"];

NSError * error = nil;

NSString * contentsOfFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: The methods for getting filePath are different here. Your answer assumes Sample.txt is bundled with the app. If it's saved to file from an earlier instance of the application, however, the original method in the question should be used.

Comment: That is correct, I assumed the file being in the bundle. Will correct my answer.

Comment: and once you've fixed that bug you should replace your wrong method call with `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`. The method you've used will give you a ExcBadAccess when it tries to write the used encoding to the address 4 (the value of NSUTF8StringEncoding).